# Ajax Uncaught TypeError: in simple function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

In my code i am getting this error

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined

but when I remove

```
delay(function(){ ... }, 1000);
```

from my source file my code works perfectly I don't know what I am doing wrong with it or missing something that is really important to do, here is my full code

```
function checkurl(textname) {
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "includes/modContent/checkurl.php",
    data: "checkurl=" + textname,
    dataType:'text', //or HTML, JSON, etc.
    success: function(response){
        //alert(response);
        textname = response;
        }
    });
    return textname;
}

$('input[name=txtPageName]').keyup(function() {
    delay(function(){
      $('input[name=txtSeoURL]').val(checkurl($(this).val()));
    }, 1000);
});

var delay = (function(){
  var timer = 0;
  return function(callback, ms){
    clearTimeout (timer);
    timer = setTimeout(callback, ms);
  };
})();
```

Comment: It's because you've changed the scope of `this` when you use it within the `setTimeout`

Comment: Also, your `checkurl` function wont return what you think it does :) - you can't return from an AJAX call

Comment: so how do I resolve it any idea or a piece of code to follow

Comment: I added an answer for you

Comment: @tymeJV I have test this checkurl function it returns from php file :) if I am wrong please clear me

Comment: You return textname from checkURL, which will be undefined, and then something inside jquery does .toLowerCase on it.  the reason textname is undefined is because of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: @James but how do I resole it

Comment: You need better understanding of async and how it works.  You can't return from an ajax function like that.  Use the callback to manipulate data returned from the server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The immediate issue, amongst others, is that you're changing the scope of `this` when you pass the callback to the `setTimeout()` handler.

To fix the issue you need to invert your logic so that you set the `val()` of the field when the AJAX completes instead of using a convoluted method of attempting to return data from an async function. Try this:

```
var timeout;
$('input[name="txtPageName]"').keyup(function() {
  clearTimeout(timeout);
  var textname = $(this).val();

  setTimeout(function() {
    $.ajax({
     type: "POST",
      url: "includes/modContent/checkurl.php",
      data: { checkurl: textname },
      dataType: 'text',
      success: function(response) {
        $('input[name=txtSeoURL]').val(response.trim());
      }
    });
  }, 250);
});
```

Comment: i have test it but it returns no value do you have any idea to fix it

Comment: You seem to have missed the point - the whole idea is not to return anything. In fact, you can't as the function is asynchronous. This answer is showing you how to use async callbacks properly.